# Permutation of string, Haskell

Tags: haskell, permutation

I have a given string: abcdpqrs, where output will be: badcqpsr.

My current code:

```
f :: [a] -> [a]
f (a:b:xs) = b:a:xs
f xs = xs
```

Evaluating `f "abcdpqrs"` results in `"bacdpqrs"`. How can this be used to get "badcqpsr"?

Comment: You asked the same question a couple of days ago and it got closed. Please do not post the same question multiple times... Instead, you should edit your original question and add your current attempt there. Anyway, you're missing a recursive call: it should be `f (a:b:xs) = b : a : f xs`.

Comment: @Jubobs thank you, if you change your comment to answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try processing more than just the first two characters by recursing on the remainder of the list:

```
f :: [a] -> [a]
f (a:b:xs) = b:a:f xs
f xs = xs
```